# 'maximum recursion depth exceeded' when loop urllib

Tags: python, httprequest, real-time, urllib

Helo, i have problem. I'm new in python. I try learn httprequest with urllib for get realtime data from site. So i try to loop with minim delay. And have error :

```
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded' in <bound method _fileobject.__del__ of <socket._fileobject object at 0x01D650F0>> ignored
```

Code

```
import urllib
import time
import os
def open(url):
    r = urllib.urlopen(url)
    #print(r.read())
    html = r.read()
    if(html!='-'):
        print('ok')
        time.sleep(0.1)
        os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')
        test()

def test():
    open('http://127.0.0.1/test/')

test()
```

Error for this Code

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp
```

Maybe you have solution for fix this code, or you have another way for realtime get data from site.

Sorry for my bad english.

Thank you

Comment: Can you show a bit more of the traceback from the exception? You don't need to show the whole thing (which would probably be hundreds of lines), but can you show us the first few and last few frames?

Comment: @Blckknght thanks for reply, i just try learn simple code, and it's full code. But now has solved :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test` calls `open` which call `test` ; cause infinite recursion.

Use loop instead to prevent such recursion:

```
import urllib
import time
import os

def check(url):
    r = urllib.urlopen(url)
    html = r.read()
    if html != '-':
        print('ok')
        time.sleep(0.1)
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

def test():
    while True:
        check('http://127.0.0.1/test/')

test()
```

BTW, [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) is a builtin function. By defining function as `open`, it shadows the builtin function. Use other name.

Comment: hy! thank you for your reply, before i have try use 'while true', but i forget why i use calls =)) . I'll try now and report again.
Thank you very much :)

Comment: I think it's work, now still looping without error. :D 
Thank you @falsetru